# wevtutil in batch file

Tags: batch-file, event-log

This is part of my batch file. I need to query from Windows event log for system events 33 and 34, this is all about the NIC speed if it is running in 100 full or 100 half duplex. Got the query from event log XML. If I run the command to query for all the events (Anytime) I am getting so many results, all I need is the latest one which is on the last line of the result.

Query for Last 7 days was a better option because it only gives me 1 result (confirmed from GUI) and it will be faster if I need to run a query to many remote PC. However running from command I am getting "A syntax error occurred at position 2. Failed to open event query. The specified query is invalid."

I wonder if the query that was generated from eventvwr have issue or it I need to escape some special characters in this query?

My second option is to just use the query for Anytime and write that last line to a file. This part I don't know how to create in batch.

Anytime:

```
wevtutil /r:%1 qe System "/q:*[System[Provider[@Name='e1kexpress'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=33 or EventID=34)]]"
```

Last 7 days

```
wevtutil /r:%1 qe System "/q:*System[Provider[@Name='e1kexpress'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=33 or EventID=34) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 604800000]]]"
```

Comment: Do you only need to find out the current NIC speed?  A Wmic query should be able to give you that info.

Answer (score 0):

Your second command has two problems (corrected parts in the code below)

```
wevtutil /r:%1 qe System "/q:*[System[
Here is the first problem.....^
```

You missed one character

```
TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 604800000]]]"
Here is the second problem........^
```

The operator is `<=`, not `&lt;=`

Comment: Ooops, the first problem was copy and paste mistake by me. The second, I really had no clue because that's what I saw in XML from event viewer and thought that it was correct, so it was a bug with Windows 7. Thank you very much for your help mc-nd

Answer (score 0):

It's to be expected that XML strings have certain characters encoded as XML entities. < and > are reserved for XML tags.

The command line utility does not need do that conversion.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML